# What is equation output voltage in oscillator?

Tags: current, amplifier, oscillator, electricity, oscillation

[image]

I was reading about oscillator circuits but could not find any equation of output voltage in terms of circuit parameters (like mutual inductance, inductance, capacitance, DC sources etc)over internet. Thus i would like if somebody derive the equation of   output voltage(This is not a homework. Just my curiosity)

Comment: are you asking for this specific circuit ?

Comment: @ManudeHanoi yes

Comment: You do not see any equation because despite the fact that the circuit looks very simple it's internal working is not so easy to grasp. The "performance" of this circuit is mainly determined by transformer parameters. Try read this as a example: https://embedderslife.wordpress.com/2015/05/13/an-analysis-of-a-joule-thief-circuit/

Comment: Maybe @jonk will have some info about where we can find the "design procedure".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sarthak....let me start with the oscillation condition: Unity loop gain at one single frequency only.

However, in order to ensure a safe start of the oscillator the loop gain must be slightly larger than "1" at t=0.

This means: Oscillations will build up and the amplitude will continuously rise...until it will be limited - either it will be clipped (hard limitation) by the supply voltage or it will be (softly) limted by any non-linearity within the loop (decreasing gain for rising amplitudes). For this purpose, many practical oscillators contain an element with a non-linear transfer characteristic (e.g. diodes).

Therefore, the ouput voltage of the oscillator is hard to predict if you do not have any information about the dominating non-linearity within the circuit.